# how to show magento's all created categories on a specific admin page?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, categories

There I am very new to magento. I already created some categories and sub categories to the magento admin. Now I have to create a select box which contain all the category as its option, and after selecting any category from that select box, I have to show a filter result which shows only the product of that selected category option.

Firstly I have no idea where the category names are store in the database, so that i can fetch these category name for the select box option value. there are so many tables in Database. I Tried so much on Internet but didn't find any thing that solve my requirement.. Hope there is someone who know how to do that. Kindly help me out. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te get name of all the active categories

```
$collection= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection() 
->addAttributeToSelect('name') 
->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');
$names = array();
foreach($collection as $col) 
{

$names[] = $col->getName();

}
```

print_r($names);

Comment: hey buddy You are great. Its working, I got a drop down which showing

Comment: categories.. Do you have any idea how to get a filter result after a selection.

Comment: Sorry but your requirement is not clear. what do you want to do and what have you tried so far?

Comment: actually I want this thing in admin area.As we done above now we have a drop box showing all categories and now I have to give this functionality to admin so that he can see the products related to that category after selecting from drop down box. I already have the list of all product, now i want to filter this on there category selection. hope I am clear.

Comment: If I am not clear you can simply tell me how to fetch products by their category id or name.

Comment: @ParamKumar refer this link http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.in/2010/12/get-products-from-particular-category.html

Answer (score 0):

First **create a static blocks** to display products of a specific categories by using this

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="SPECIFIC CATEGORY ID" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Then create a new category select box.
Under that create sub-categories with name of all other categories and in display settings select display mode as static blocks.

Under that select the respective block made using the main category ids.

That's it.

Comment: this is not work for me because I want this thing in admin area and your code sounds like for front area which is not require for me. I have to give this functionality to admin so that he can see the products related to that category after selecting from drop down.